# CSS convert pixels in % issue - calculation not right

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a container (`div.wrap`) of 640px × 890px.

I want to add a `padding-top` of 40px, but in %. So 40px / 890px = 4.4943820225%

```
.body { width: 640px; height: 890px; }
.wrap {
 padding-top: 4.4943820225%;
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

But when I check on the Chrome dev tool, I have `padding-top` = 28.750px. Why is that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you replicate this issue on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the specification http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding-top, the paddings (*all sides*) are calculated in relation to the width when using percentages..

Quote

> **Percentages:**      refer to ***width*** of containing block

Comment: I've answered exactly the same thing 2mins earlier. Why did you get the best answer?? **UNFAIR!**

Comment: @sam have a read at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-upvotes

Comment: got it. But how come will I be able to get rep. like yours if it happens quite often

Answer (score 1):

because it rounds these 4,4943820225% a bit and calculate them from the **width** of the parent element.

so, 640px x 4,49..% = 28,7px

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp

> % - Specifies the padding in percent of the width of the containing element